# Try Catch and Static Variables

Tags: c++, exception, static, try-catch

Suppose I am doing something like:

```
try
{
   do_job();
}
catch(...)
{
   std::cout << "GUI is running so we won't terminate and raise a clear error here instead" << std::endl;
};
```

When calling a failing `do_job` some `static` variables/classes are initiated, are they "destroyed" after the catch? If not how to handle this please (i.e. memory allocated to statics)?

My generic problem is: I am having a GUI looping to display stuff to the user, say a game, if an error occur, the program will call `std::termniate()` I guess, or something similar, but I will find myself in the lovely file `<abort>`, the GUI then is crached, how can I handle this and reset static variables created when `do_job` is called please? Shoud I just let them initiated? The user in this case might change mind and not even use the static variables that have been created, so they are there with no use taking memory?

Comment: function local static variables are initialized the first time execution passes the variable and are destroyed when the program ends.  If your program crashed then the memory they were using will be cleaned up by the OS.

Comment: What do you mean by crashed please? Inside the `try, catch` block? Because for me I am not crashing at all if I use `try catch`?

Comment: @Vero Using a `try catch` doesn't mean a crash doesn't happpen. It just means that you are trying to handle the crash and move on.

Comment: Yes, it's just word usage not precise :) I agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

Static storage duration variables, if they have been successfully initialized, will always be destroyed at normal program termination, not earlier.

If a static variable wasn't successfully initialized then it will not be destroyed.

In any case there is nothing for you to take care of under normal conditions. In particular when throwing from `do_job`, either the `static` has been fully initialized at the point of the `throw` or it hasn't been. In the former case it will be destroyed at normal program termination, in the latter case it doesn't need to be destroyed.

In the situation of a `std::terminate` call, it looks different. It is called under *abnormal* conditions, such as if an exception is uncaught or an exception thrown while stack unwinding is in progress or an exception escapes a `noexcept` function.

The default `std::terminate` handler will call `std::abort` which abnormally terminates the program and explicitly does *not* destruct any static storage duration objects. The program just abruptly terminates without any chance to execute any further instructions (except maybe for a `SIGABRT` handler).

The `std::terminate` handler can be replaced, but the conditions under which `std::terminate` is called don't really allow for normal program termination and surely not for sensible continuation of program execution.

The best solution is to not let the abnormal conditions causing it to be called happen. Make sure to not let exceptions escape from `main`, destructors or `noexcept` functions. (There are more sources of `std::terminate` calls. All of them should be avoided.)

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thanks very much!! I just let them live then :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> When calling a failing do_job some static variables/classes are initiated, are they "destroyed" after the catch?

Variables with static storage duration are destroyed after `main` returns (either normally, or call to `std::exit`).

Comment: Yes, Thank you! But `main` never returns? I am inside a looping GUI. I am using `try catch`, so I am not crashing, and I am not out of main!

Comment: @Vero `static` is not the right tool for this job, I'm afraid. Hard to say exactly what is without specific details, though.

Comment: I agree it's a generic statement, but I think all I was looking for is to know if I should do something about it, apparently the response from @user17732522 says I can't and better avoid falling in this at the first place :)

Comment: @Vero `I am not out of main!` Then static variables will not have been destroyed yet.